# How do I check if a value has been entered already? In a do while loop?

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

This getsize method asks for numbers to blank in a square matrix. After input it returns the new matrix. I would like to check these values in a do-while loop. I added the full code. I would like to print out if one of the entered values occurs more than once and then give the option to change that spot in the matrix to a new number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class square {

```
    private int [][]matrixblank;
    private int firstrow;
    private int number;
    private int count;

    public square() {

        matrixblank=getsize();
        firstrow=0;
        number=0;
        count=0;


    }

    public int [][]getsize() {
        int rows=0;
        int f=0;
        Scanner size = new Scanner(System.in);
        //THIS SETS SIZE OF THE MATRIX 
        System.out.println("How big do you want your magic square?");
        rows=size.nextInt();
        while(rows<1){
        System.out.println("Enter an accepted value of the size of your magic square");
        rows=size.nextInt();}
            // END OF SETTING MATRIX 

        // FINDS  VALUE OF THE NUMBERS IN THE MATRIX 
        int matrix[][]= new int [rows][rows];
        for(int row=0; row<matrix.length;row++){
            for(int column=0;column<matrix[row].length;column++){
                System.out.println("Enter value for"+ row + " "+ column);
                f=size.nextInt();
                matrix[row][column]=f;
                //END OF FINDING VALUES 

        //CHECKS TO SEE IF THE VALUE IS TOO BRING OR SMALL
                while(f<1||f>matrix.length*matrix.length){
                    System.out.println("This number is too big or small please. Enter a new Number.");
                    f=size.nextInt();
                    matrix[row][column]=f;
                }
        //END OF CHECKING IF THE VALUE IS IN BOUNDS

                if(matrix[row][column]==f){
                    System.out.println("Enter a new number that hasnt been entered before");
                    f=size.nextInt();
                    matrix[row][column]=f;
                }



            }}



        return matrix;
    }


    public void sumoffirstrow() {

            for(int firstrow1=0;firstrow1<matrixblank[0].length;firstrow1++) {
                firstrow+=matrixblank[0][firstrow1];
                number=firstrow;
        }
    }


    public boolean checkrows(){

    int sumrows=0;
        for(int a=0;a<matrixblank.length;a++){
            sumrows=0;
            for(int b=0;b<matrixblank.length;b++){
                sumrows+=matrixblank[a][b];
            }
            if(sumrows!=number){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
        public boolean checkcolumns(){


        int sumcolumns=0;
        for(int c =0; c < matrixblank.length; c++){
              sumcolumns = 0;

         for(int d = 0; d< matrixblank.length; d++){
                  sumcolumns += matrixblank[d][c];
              }
              if(sumcolumns != number){
                  return false;
              }
        }
        return true;

        }
        public boolean TLBR(){



        int sumofLtoR;
        sumofLtoR=0;
        for(int e=0;e<matrixblank.length;e++){
            sumofLtoR+=matrixblank[e][e];
        }
        if(sumofLtoR!=number){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }


        public boolean TRBL(){


        int sumofRtoL;
        sumofRtoL=0;
        for(int f=0;f<matrixblank.length;f++){
            sumofRtoL+=matrixblank[f][matrixblank.length-1-f];
        }
        if(sumofRtoL!=number){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    public String getnumbers() {
        String b = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < matrixblank.length; i++){
            b +="\n";
            for(int j = 0; j < matrixblank[0].length; j++){
                b += " " + matrixblank[i][j];
            }

        }
        return b;   

    }





    public String toString() {



        if(checkrows()&&checkcolumns()&&TLBR()&&TRBL()){
            return "This is a magic square"+getnumbers();
        }

        else{


        return "This is not a magic square\n"+getnumbers();
        }
        }



        }
```

Comment: you mean you want to replace the for loops with do while? why?

Comment: What do you want to check? Each value is an int, otherwise there's an exception. If you want to check something, do it at the position where each value is set.

Comment: I would like to check if the value entered is entered more than once.